# Request location updates from BOOT_COMPLETED Receiver?

Tags: android, gps, broadcastreceiver, bootcompleted

I need to get location updates form onReceive method. When the the onReceive() called the GPS start for 2-3 second and gone, why??

HOW to fix it?? i want to get location updates. help please.

NOTE: onReceive method is called when restarting my phone

The java code:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements LocationListener {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction()))
 {
    LocationManager LM2=(LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LM2.requestLocationUpdates("gps",5000, 0, this);
 }

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

<receiver android:name="com.my.package.BootReceiver">
       <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: because a broadcast receiver is short-lived. use a service instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> When the the onReceive() called the GPS start for 2-3 second and gone, why?

Because your process was terminated.

Comment: OK. how to fix it??
please complete your answer

Answer (score 2):

Thanx guys for your help, all i needed was to make a [Service](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html)

the onReceive method will be

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

   if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction()))
  {
     Intent i= new Intent(context, MyService.class);            
     context.startService(i);
  }

}
```

MyService class

```
public class MyService extends Service implements LocationListener {


     @Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

      @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //TODO do something useful
    LocationManager LM2=(LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LM2.requestLocationUpdates("gps",5000, 0, this);
    return Service.START_STICKY;
  }


    @Override
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

 @Override
 public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 @Override
  public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

and i need to register my service in the manifest.xml

```
<service
 android:name="com.my.package.MyService"
 android:icon="@drawable/icon"
 android:label="Service name"
 >
 </service>
```